# Align last subfigure on the left side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, alignment, includegraphics

I have 5 pictures and want to align them that three pictures are on the left side above each other and two on the right side.
I have tried it like this

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_09_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 1: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_10_11.png}
\caption{Measurement 2: 1:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 2}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 3: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_11.png}
\caption{Measurement 4: 1:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 4}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[h]{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth, left]{pictures/deltaphi_11_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 5: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 5}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Phase shift of the different plasma measurements over their incident power.}
\label{fig:delta phi over P} 
\end{figure}
```

My problem is that the last picture is still in the center but I want it exactly under the two left pictures.

Comment: There is no `[h]` option to `subfigure` and it's simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would delete all `\centering` directives, set the widths of the individual graphs to `1\textwidth` rather than `0.9\textwidth`, insert `\hfill` directives between adjacent `subfigure` environments, and issue `\medskip` directives between the rows of subfigures. And, for good measure, do consider loading a LaTeX chemistry package, such as [mhchem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem), and replacing all instances of `CO$_2$` with `\ce{CO2}`. (I believe that "ce" is short for "chemical expression".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption} % for subfigure environment
\usepackage{mhchem}     % for \ce macro
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0.333\baselineskip} % place captions closer to graphs

\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_09_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 1: 2:1 \ce{CO2}-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_10_11.png}
\caption{Measurement 2: 1:1 \ce{CO2}-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 3: 2:1 \ce{CO2}-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_11.png}
\caption{Measurement 4: 1:1 \ce{CO2}-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 4}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_11_21.png}
\caption{Measurement 5: 2:1 \ce{CO2}-Argon.}
\label{fig:delta phi 5}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Phase shift of the different plasma measurements over their incident power.}
\label{fig:delta phi over P} 

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works fantastic

Answer (score 2):

Add a "fake image" in the form of `\hspace{0.48\textwidth}` after the final (5th) image.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_09_21.png}
    \caption{Measurement 1: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_10_11.png}
    \caption{Measurement 2: 1:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_21.png}
    \caption{Measurement 3: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_08_11.png}
    \caption{Measurement 4: 1:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}{.48\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{pictures/deltaphi_11_21.png}
    \caption{Measurement 5: 2:1 CO$_2$-Argon.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hspace{.48\textwidth}\mbox{}
  \caption{Phase shift of the different plasma measurements over their incident power.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to add vertical whitespace (e.g., via `\medskip` instructions) to assure that the subfigure captions are closer to their associated graphs than to the graphs below them.

Comment: When I implemented it in my document the last picture was a bit shiftet more left than the pictures above. But still thank you a lot!